# Find space given homology group

Tags: algebraic-topology, homological-algebra

I'm a bit lost in a question where I'm given that $H_5(X,\mathbb{R}) = \mathbb{Z} \oplus \mathbb{Z}_3$ and i need to find such topological space $X$.

How do I look for such space? And which one will it be?

Comment: "Wchich one" sounds as if you'd expect there to only be one such space. There are plenty upon plenty such spaces. How to come up with an example depends on what you know. Do you know what the homology groups of a disjoint union look like? What the homology groups of spheres look like? What the homology groups of a space with an $n$-cell attached look like? What homology groups of suspensions look like? Combining some of these ideas can give you many examples.

Comment: I'm not convinced there _are_ such spaces $X$. Do you mean $H_5(X, \mathbb{Z})$? After all, homology with coefficients in $\mathbb{R}$ must be an $\mathbb{R}$-vector space (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/190122/homology-with-field-coefficients), say), but $\mathbb{Z} \oplus \mathbb{Z}/3$ isn't.

Comment: The fact coefficients were in $\mathbb{R}$ were a main issue, but I couldn't decide wheter it was a typpo or not. It seems so then.

As for the which one, i mean how to look for candidates, I know uniqueness is not to be expected. I'm used to celular homology as with sphere homology groups.

Comment: Can you find a space with $H_5 \cong \mathbb{Z}$? Another space with $H_5 \cong \mathbb{Z}/3$ (both with integer coefficients)? Given two such spaces, can you solve your problem?

Comment: Yes, just attach then as a disjoint union, it makes sense, i will try doing it